# Strip json object in Ansible if key exists

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Say I have a json object like this:

```
{
 "results": [ 
    {
    "failed": "no",
    "data": "another string"
    },
    "failed": "no", 
    "skipped": true
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to strip the json of any object that has "skipped" defined in an ansible playbook? So I would just have

```
{
 "results": [ 
    {
    "failed": "no",
    "data": "another string"
    }
}
```

Comment: If key exists or the value is `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [rejectattr](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#rejectattr) filter:

```
{ results | rejectattr('skipped') | list }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering the literal request:

> strip the json of any object that has "skipped" defined

```
{{ results | rejectattr('skipped','defined') | list }
```